# Scraping script object value on a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** an image from a website. And this image URL stores on a script object.

[image]

I want to **scrape** viewModel.productThumbs.ImageURL.
Also Im new to python and beatifulsoap.

In my source code I applied like that:

```
# Import request library
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Extracting html
url_path = ('URL')
html_text = requests.get(url_path).text


# Getting a Beautiful Soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

scripts = soup.find_all('script', 'viewModel')
print(scripts)
```

So I cannot **scrape** this ImageUrl info. How can I solve this?

Comment: Fyi it’s __scraping__ not scrapping, __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup cannot parse Javascript/Json data. you can use different method - for example `re`/`json` modules, for example (as I don't know URL, you need to adapt it to your case):

```
import re
import json


html_text = """
    <script>
        viewModel = {
            "productThumbs": [{
                "ImageUrl": "your image url"
            }],
            "other_info":[]
        };

    </script>
"""

data = re.search(r"viewModel = (.*});", html_text, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

print(data["productThumbs"][0]["ImageUrl"])
```

This prints:

```
your image url
```